# Sending two text files with mail command - No -a support

Tags: linux, mail-command

I searched but did not find this answer. I am running an old RedHat 5.3 system on one server (working on upgrade to 7 in progress) but I want to send 2 text files using the mail command. I do this all the time with a single file like this:

```
mail username -s 'MySubject' < /home/directory/file1.txt
```

I tried this:

```
mail username -s 'MySubject' < /home/directory/file1.txt < /home/directory/file2.txt
```

But that send the output of the first part including the results of the mail command along with both text files.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to concatenate the two files into a single unit before piping them to the `mail` command. Like this, for example:

```
cat /home/directory/file1.txt /home/directory/file2.txt | mail username -s 'MySubject'
```